# Polygonize(raster to vector)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, installation, polygonize

I have been install QGIS 2.0.1.when I use Polygonize (Raster to vector)for convert jpg to shp I get error message such as:

> C:\windows\123.exe is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,  operable program or batch file.

Please help me to fix it.
thanks

Comment: Can you share the file that you need to convert? Easiest first check would be trying it out on a second computer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably about a keylogger virus completely unrelated to QGIS.

Comment: In support of @MappaGnosis' assessment, see http://www.threatexpert.com/files/123.exe.html for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your computer may be infected with a virus unrelated to QGIS.  "123.exe" Is listed on many virus forums as a key logger.  Clean your computer and then re-install QGIS.  QGIS itself is clean and safe so you acquired the virus from some other source.